# Using iOS for existing .Net MVC database

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I currently have an MVC 4 app running on a Windows Azure website. Some of the users need to use the app, but may be at a location without internet access. The goal is to have an iPad app with offline capability, and will push the changes to the Windows Azure database when an internet connection is established. I am in the planning process, and I have questions about how both apps can use the same database concurrently. When I create a Windows Azure Mobile Service and use the same database the Azure dashboard does not show the existing tables used by the MVC app. Is it possible for both the iOS app and MVC 4 app to use the same tables, or am I going to have to go a different way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to write web api against your database,its very easy to Write Web Api 2 that can easily communicate with any sort of device or application because it is HTTP based.I personally have done this. Web api returns xml or JSON based data you can use this to populate your local database in your iOS Application.

You can also implement some logic to save data back to the database when you got connected to the internet.

Comment: I have looked into using Web API 2, and have started on a Web API 2 project that will handle the client requests. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS app should absolutely *not* connect directly to your database. I actually don't think it's possible through the iOS SDK to do that if you wanted to, anyways, but just in case: don't.

Instead, your iOS app should connect to an API that you will need to build. The API, alone, will interact with the database. You can also retrofit your existing website to use the API as well, removing database concurrency issues entirely.